# If statement not working in React component.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm fetching the data from a weather api and want it to animate using this component. For e.g if the temperature is above say 20, I want the 'const sunny' to be displayed. I've gotten as far as to make it appear once the data is fetched but the 'if' statement is not working as no matter what the temp. is, it still calls the 'cloudy' variable.

The weather is being fetched by a 'getWeather' function in the App.jsx component.Please help. What am I missing?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactAnimatedWeather from 'react-animated-weather';

const sunny = {
    icon: 'CLEAR_DAY',
    color: 'red',
    size: 200,
    animate: true
  };

  const cloudy = {                                      
    icon: 'PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY',
    color: 'blue',
    size: 200,
    animate: true
  };

export default class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
      animationData : 
      { icon: '',
      color: '',
      size: 0,
      animate: false},
      hasrecieved : true
      }

    this.getanimation = this.getanimation.bind(this)
  }

getanimation() { 
  let animationData = this.state.animationData
if (this.state.temperature < 1) {
  animationData = sunny
} else {
 animationData = cloudy
}
  this.setState({
    animationData: animationData,
    hasrecieved: true
  })
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
    if (this.props !== nextProps) {
    this.setState(nextProps)
  }
  this.getanimation()  
}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
        <div>
    { this.state.hasrecieved && <ReactAnimatedWeather
      icon={this.state.animationData.icon}
      color={this.state.animationData.color}
      size={this.state.animationData.size}
      animate={this.state.animationData.animate}
    />}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: My best guess is that the API returns the temperature as a string. I would recommend parsing it to a number and using trying the condition again. `parseFloat(string)`

Comment: @ChiragRavindra: The OP is using `<`, which would implicitly convert.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder from my understanding, the implicit conversion only works when there is no units.. So `"11" < 12` would work but `"11°C" < 12` would not...

Comment: @ChiragRavindra: True, you'd get `NaN` if the entire string can't be parsed, whereas `parseFloat` will parse the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

[`setState` is **asynchronous**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Your `getanimation` is using `this.state` and is called immediately after `setState`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
  if (this.props !== nextProps) {
    this.setState(nextProps)
  }
  this.getanimation()  
}
```

To ensure it gets called after that state change has actually been made, use the second argument to `setState`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
  if (this.props !== nextProps) {
    this.setState(nextProps, this.getanimation)
  } else {
    this.getanimation()
  }
}
```

Separately, note that `this.props !== nextProps` will **always** be true. The properties may be *equivalent*, but they won't be the *same object*.

Comment: Still don't completely understand how it works but it does. Thank you so much.